# Integrating solr with Drupal using own MySQL db

Tags: mysql, drupal, solr

I have started to work on joint utilization of Drupal and solr.

I have indexed my mysql database with solr and I am able to run queries on solr admin panel.
Long story short, I want to create a simple search page using drupal and utilizing this on records which I have indexed using solr. Could you please share the process steps or video tutorial which will lead me to run this on drupal?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar with my own custom Drupal module. The best advice I can give you is to download and explore the [Apache Solr Drupal Module](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) (note you will also need to download the [solr-php-client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) as well). The Apache Solr Module will give you a good framework for how to call out to Solr and display results within Drupal. I used this Module as the basis for my own custom module.

If you are new to creating custom modules in Drupal I would recommend the following books.

- For Drupal 6 - [Pro Drupal Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430209895) by K. VanDyk
- For Drupal 7 - [Pro Drupal 7 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228385) by T. Tomlinson